# Custom Validation for Dates uisng Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I want some help with date between `loanStartDate` and `loanEndDate` using Fluent Validation. The input date format is in string. I actually want specific error messages for specific scenarios.

Below is the example what I tried so far:

```
public class LoanSearchTypeValidator:> AbstractValidator<LoanSearchType>  
{  
    public LoanSearchTypeValidator() 
    {
        RuleFor(t => t.loanStartDate).Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
                                     .Must(BeValidateLoanDate);
            
        RuleFor(t => t.loanEndDate).Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
                                   .Must((date, obj) => BeValidateLoanEndDate)
                                   .When(k => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(k.loanStartDate);  
    } 
            
    private <bool > BeValidateLoanDate(string val)  
    {  
        var res = false;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(val, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,> DateTimeStyle.None, out DateTime dt)  
        { 
            if(dt.Year >= 1900 && > dt.Year <= 2099)  
            {  
                res = true;  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                res = false; 
            } 
        }

        return res;  
    }  

    private <bool > BeValidateLoanEndDate(string enddt, string strtdt)  
    {  
        var res = false;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(enddt, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,> DateTimeStyle.None, out DateTime end)  
        { 
            if (end.Year >= 1900 && > end.Year <= 2099)  
            {  
                res = true;  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                res = false; 
            }
        }    

        if (DateTime.TryParse(strtdt, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,> DateTimeStyle.None, out DateTime start)
        {
            if (end > start)
            {
                res = true;
            }
            else
            {
                res = false;
            }
        }

        return res;  
    }
} 

Public class LoanSearchType
{
    public string loanStartDate { get; set; }
    public string loanEndDate { get; set; }
}
```

I need messages like "Date is in wrong format", "Date doesn't come within permissable year range", "end date cannot be less than start Date". I need you sincere help.

Comment: Do you specifically need the error messages to be 'Date is in wrong format', 'Date doesn't come within permissable year range', and 'end date cannot be less than start Date'? Or do you need to inject the dates? The WithMessage option allows you to specify the message for a rule and it has a lambda overload to inject the instance to validate properties.

Comment: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/configuring.html#overriding-the-message

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `PropertyValidatorContext context` to parameters of your method, then handle errors like this:

```
if(condition)
   context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("ValidationMessage", "First."); 
if(secondCondition)
   context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("ValidationMessage", "Second.");
if(anotherCondition)
   context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("ValidationMessage", "Another.");
```